# Blue Prism Decision stage to ignore letter capitalization

Tags: case-insensitive, blueprism

I am new to Blue Prism and trying to develop a bot that will do some searches on a CRM portal. The bot should search for a certain customer in the web-based CRM app database, and should select the correct one, based on the information provided in an Excel file.

For example, my Excel file has the following information:

Customer name: BLABLA LTD
  Contact: test.email@example.com
  First Name: John
  Last Name: Smith

The bot will use the information in the cells above to perform the search in the web portal, but the web portal contains information which is sometimes in capital letters. I have managed to make the bot go through each element in the webpage that contains a search result, but I want it to click on the one that matches the information above. I used a decision stage, so if the Customer name in the table is the same as in the element, then it will click on it.

The problem is in the table, the text is capitalized, but in the web form it's not, so Blue Prism will consider that the value is different. Is there any way that I can make the bot ignore the capitalization when performing the calculation logic? What I am doing now is adding a new calculation stage to store all the elements in lowercase, and afterwards perform the equality logic between the new lowercase variables, but I was hoping there is an easier way.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to spy elements based on case insensitive criteria or are you trying to make a case insensitive comparison in a decision stage?

Comment: Hi, I have already spied the elements, I am now trying to make a case insensitive comparison in a decision stage.

Answer (score 5):

You can usually use `Lower()` or `Upper()` on both strings, that will make sure the two of them are in the same casing:

[image]

You will see the function available under `Text` if you want to see more details about it.